# What is "@" doing in a CSS file?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

When following the TailwindCSS configuration tutorial to set it up using Next.js, the `.css` file at the top level looks like:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

My question is: What is this doing and how is it grabbing and utilizing the tailwind CSS files?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Tailwind Functions & Directives docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#tailwind):

> **`@tailwind`**
> Use the @tailwind directive to insert Tailwind’s `base`, `components`, `utilities` and `variants` styles into your CSS.
>
> ```css
> /**
>  * This injects Tailwind's base styles and any base styles registered by
>  * plugins.
>  */
>  @tailwind base;
>
>  /**
>   * This injects Tailwind's component classes and any component classes
>   * registered by plugins.
>   */
>  @tailwind components;
>  
>  /**
>   * This injects Tailwind's utility classes and any utility classes registered
>   * by plugins.
>   */
>  @tailwind utilities;
>  
>  /**
>   * Use this directive to control where Tailwind injects the hover, focus,
>   * responsive, dark mode, and other variants of each class.
>   *
>   * If omitted, Tailwind will append these classes to the very end of
>   * your stylesheet by default.
>   */
>  @tailwind variants;
> ```

As for how they work-- it appears from the [installation page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) where they reference leveraging these directives the next step is "**Start the Tailwind CLI build process:** Run the CLI tool to scan your template files for classes and build your CSS."  My assumption would be that this build process is what is reading these directives and transpiling them into usable CSS for the browser to consume.

Comment: Is this not a CSS syntax to import using "@", what is achieving the parsing of the globals.css to grab the tailwind css? I can't find any documentation on CSS files allowing "@"

Comment: @Joe - There's plenty of use of @ to start an [at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule) in CSS. `@tailwind` however is not CSS.

Comment: How does tailwind make their own custom at-rule and what tool would be used to understand it?

Comment: @Joe, that's explained in the answer above. It's a directive to the tailwind transpiler.